# AWK - How to replace a line beginning with?

Tags: awk

I'd like to use awk (because I can't use sed or grep) to substitute all lines beginning with **TEST=**
by **"TEST=MY LINE"**

For exemple

My file :

```
aaaa 
bbb
ccc
TEST=ABC DDE FFE GGG
bdd
mmp
kff
fds
```

What I'd like :

```
aaaa 
bbb
ccc
TEST=MY LINE
bdd
mmp
kff
fds
```

How could I do to obtain this result ?
I found how to do when I know the exact line, but I can't find how to replace with the beginning.

Many thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^TEST=/ { print "TEST=MY LINE"; next; }; { print; }' input

aaaa 
bbb
ccc
TEST=MY LINE
bdd
mmp
kff
fds
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(TEST=\).*/\1MY LINE/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by 3 methods

command1:

```
awk '/^TEST=/{gsub(".*","TEST=MY LINE",$0)}1' filename
```

command2:

```
sed '/^TEST=/s/.*/TEST=MY LINE/g' filename
```

command3

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'^TEST=')
y=open('p.txt','r')
for i in y:
    if re.search(k,i):
        o=re.sub("k.*","kMY LINE",i)
        print o.strip()
    else:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
aaaa
bbb
ccc
TEST=ABC DDE FFE GGG
bdd
mmp
kff
fds
```